# Is it okay to define controls in ui then copy attributes from them for structures harder to implement dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just thought about doing this for the first time today. The idea is when a class structure is harder to implement dynamically than it is through ui/html side, you build a ui object and set to to disabled, then copy any of these harder to implement attributes off of the inactive control to your dynamically created instance.

Ideally it'd be cool if there was an easy dynamic solution but in cases like interface members it's time consuming to build a class and implement.

Anyone have thoughts like downfalls or things to watch out for?

Here's an example of a situation where I think this makes sense. I want to add an empty data template to my mainGrid gridview user control. The user control is primarily dynamically created based on the input to the user control on the backend. While needing to add a comment in the case of being empty, I found that the user Grid already takes this in and handles it. So I was going to dynamically add this to my MainGrid until I realized that to do this, I'd be forced to implement an ITemplate in a custom class and write custom logic in there. However, all I really wanted was to add a text literal control so it seemed way overkill to go down that route. So instead I declared a disabled UI element that contained the design I wanted, then in the back end I assigned MainGrid.EmptyDataTemplate with EmptyDataTemplateAsString.EmptyDataTemplate.

```html
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="MainGrid"/>

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="EmptyDataTemplateAsString" Enabled="false">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <%#NoDataMessage%>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

```
MainGrid.EmptyDataTemplate = EmptyDataTemplateAsString.EmptyDataTemplate;
            EmptyDataTemplateAsString.EmptyDataTemplate = null;
```

This allowed me the dynamic assignment based on the passed in parameters w/o needing to clutter my backend with the implementation of an ITemplate, just for the sake of a textLiteralControl.

I figured this design could not only extend to scenarios like this, but also to scenarios where I just want to mimic a design and re-use it dynamically across a single page. I know this is similar to a user control but it doesn't require that I create a new UC file every time and to me this would be used more in scenarios where a standard uc isn't necessarily going to be an advantage across multiple screens.

Comment: HTML attributes and classes/interface looks disconnected... can you explain what's the use case you are trying to solve with an example?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET WebForms (traditional (20 year old) ASP.NET) or ASP.NET MVC